# Running Karma from TeamCity

Tags: node.js, angularjs, teamcity, karma-runner

Does anyone know how you would run the following command within TeamCity? (the command is normally ran in a Node.js command window)..."Karma start karma.conf.js". I have successfully installed Nodejs on the TeamCity server. I have then successfully installed Karma on  the same server (using npm install -g karma).

In TeamCity, my build step has "Runner type = Command Line", and the Custom Script is set to "FULLPATHOFKARMAEXE\karma.cmd start FULLPATHOFKARMACONFIGFILE/kara.conf.js"

When i run TeamCity, it comes back with the error "node is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Anyone know the step-by step process of running Karma within TeamCity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, the Karma installation seems to be OK, but your TeamCity agent process is unable to resolve the path to Node.exe (it's installation folder is missing from the `%PATH%` variable).

First verify the NodeJS installation by opening a Commandline window on the agent machine, type `node` and press enter:

```
c:> node
>
```

If the result in your Command window is a `>`-prompt, you might solve your problems by restarting the build agent.

If the result in your Command window is some error message saying "*node is not recognized as an internal or external command*", you need to add the NodeJS installation folder to the `%PATH%` variable, and restart the build agent.

You can, of course, just change the `%PATH%` for your build agent service by running a initialization script included in the NodeJS installtion folder in your build step. Depending on where your NodeJS installastion is, your custom script might look like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\nodevars.bat"
"FULLPATHOFKARMAEXE\karma.cmd start FULLPATHOFKARMACONFIGFILE/kara.conf.js"
```